# Creating multiple linked lists with one program

Tags: c++, c, linked-list

I am new to linked lists and I am trying to write a programe where we can simply pass new heads to the add() function and create as many lists as we want. But somehow the code is not working at all. From the output it seems every time I call add() function, even with the same head address, a new fresh head is created.

Can anyone please tell me how to proceed?

This what I have written:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
  struct node *next;
  int val;
};


void add(int i,node** h,node** e)
{
  node* head = *h;
  node* endnode = *e;
  printf("adding\n");
  if(head!=NULL)
  {
      node *n = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
      n->next  = NULL;
      n->val = i;

      endnode->next = n;
      endnode = n;
  }
  else
  {
      printf("heading\n");
      head  = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
      head->next = NULL;
      head->val = i;
      endnode = head;
  }

  }

  void delete_node(int i,node** h,node** e)
  {
    node* head = *h;
    node* endnode = *e;
    node *temp;
    node *n = head;
    while(n!=NULL)
    {
     if(n->val == i)
     {
        if(n==head)
        {
            head = head->next;
        }
        else if(n==endnode)
        {
            temp->next = NULL;
            endnode = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            temp->next = n->next;       
        }
        free(n);
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        temp = n;
        n = n->next;
    }
  }
}

 void display(node** h)
 {
   node* head = *h;

   node *n = head;

   while(n!=NULL)
   {
    printf("%d\n",n->val);
    n = n->next;
   }
 }



int main()
{

  node *head  = NULL;
  node *endnode  = NULL;    

  add(5,&head,&endnode);
  add(8,&head,&endnode);
  add(1,&head,&endnode);
  add(78,&head,&endnode);
  add(0,&head,&endnode);

  display(&head);
  printf("\n\n");

  system("pause");
  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Why are `h` and `e` double pointers?

Comment: beacause I am passing address of  pointer *head and *endnode i.e. reference to the pointers. I dont if its fundamentally correct.. please tell me if I am wrong

Comment: Tagged c++, why use `malloc`? Why not use STL?

Comment: Single pointers would suffice. All you do is read the value of what the double pointer is pointing to, which you could do perfectly fine with one. It's comparable to doing `int *i` instead of `int i` in those same functions.

Comment: Are you sure you don't use C?

Comment: What about having `node *head1  = NULL;` and `node *head2  = NULL;` to scale out?!? And eliminate that weird `node *endnode  = NULL;`!!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - is NULL for C, why not nullptr?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ yes thats one solution I thought of, but thats not what I am looking for. Thanks for help.

Comment: @EdHeal Is this really relevant here?!? Could be `node *head1  = nullptr;` very well alternatively!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - Bring software up to date

Comment: @chirag-agrawal That was an invalid edit! at least `using namespace std;` clearly states this is c++ code!!

Comment: A downvote, already?? Woww!! I came here because I am learning and not an expert in pointers. As @Macro A. says, there is a cleaner design possible for this problem.But I dont know what is it, thats why I came here. I tried searching a lot but got nothing.

Comment: @ChiragAgrawal if you get upset over every little downvote, you're in for a lot of angry moments. Don't let it bother you. (P.S: I'm not the one who downvoted you)

Comment: Use `std::vector` or `std::list`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Aside from the design and straight to your question**, the problem is:

1. You create a pointer in main()

   ```
   node *head  = NULL;
   ```
2. You pass its address to the function thus having a pointer to a pointer

   ```
   void add(int i,node** h,node** e)
   ```
3. You dereference it thus having the exact pointer outside

   ```
   node* head = *h;
   ```
4. You assign **to the local copy of the pointer**

   ```
   head  = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
   ```
5. You continue happily thinking that you've updated the pointer I listed in 1.

As a personal opinion I agree with the comments: you could get away with a cleaner design instead of those double pointers.

---

Edit: to help you understand, here's a correct version with your exact design

```
void add(int i,node** h,node** e)
{
    printf("adding\n");
    if(*h!=NULL)
    {
        node *n = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        n->next  = NULL;
        n->val = i;

        (*e)->next = n;
        *e = n;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("heading\n");
        *h  = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        (*h)->next = NULL;
        (*h)->val = i;
        *e = *h;
    }

}
```

In your first version you were doing this (pseudocode):

```
void functon(int** ptrToPtrToInt) {
  int* ptrToInt = *ptrToPtrToInt; // suppose ptrToInt now contains 0x20 (the address of the integer)
  ptrToInt = malloc(sizeof(int)); // ptrToInt loses the 0x20 and gets a new address
} // ptrToInt gets destroyed, but nobody updated the pointer where ptrToPtrToInt came from, thus is unchanged
```

Comment: so should I allocate memory to head in the main function itself??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of using just node, create a stuct for a list.

```
struct list{
    node *head;
    int size;
}
void add(list *l, node *n){
    // check nulls
    // check size = 0
    // add and increment size
}
```

Then have all your functions work off of that instead of your nodes that way you can actually create more than one.

Pass in the list pointer instead so you have access to the head of the list. pass in the node to add there you go.